# Enable WebRTC in Firefox for whitelisted sites only

Tags: networking, firefox, privacy

I would like to have WebRTC generally blocked in my Firefox browser, except for a small set of websites which I trust and which need this functionality.

I know one can disable WebRTC in Firefox by setting `media.peerconnection.enabled` in `about:config` to `False`, but that affects all sites.

Is there any setting, add-on or maybe even anything outside the browser that can let me block all WebRTC traffic except for a few destination sites?

Comment: You could consider having a separate profile for trusted sites. In this profile, you wouldn't disable WebRTC. [man firefox](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/firefox.1.html) explains how to set up profiles and even how to run more than one profile at the same time.

Comment: @DKBose Thanks, but while this is true and an interesting idea I didn't have before, it would be a very inconvenient solution, as those profiles would not share history, tabs, settings, add-ons etc, making their usage quite complicated.

Comment: Please see http://kb.mozillazine.org/Transferring_data_to_a_new_profile_-_Firefox for "cloning" a profile. Once you do that, you could make the necessary change.

Comment: The cloning once wouldn't be that much a of a problem, but I don't want to have to deal with two different profiles that get out of sync at all. And I'd always have to pay attention to what window I'm currently in and e.g. avoid opening links in the same window etc. My current workaround is an add-on that lets you easily toggle WebRTC for the whole browser, but I can briefly enable the setting to start a call in my trusted site and then disable it again. That is still less effort than handling two profiles. Sorry, not a fan your suggestion.